# weird bug with gtk and webkit

Tags: python, gtk, webkit, gnome

okay so i am working on a simple web browser made with gtk and webkit for my portfolio, i decided to use a gnome application template from gnome's builder ide and it works, however when i try to import webkit2 to my main.py file i get this error:

```
ImportError: Requiring namespace 'Gtk' version '3.0', but '4.0' is already loaded
```

here is everything that i am importing

```py
import sys
import gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '4.0')
gi.require_version('Adw', '1')

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio, Adw
from .window import WebnavigatorWindow, AboutDialog
from gi.repository import WebKit2
```

and i have no idea why this happens could someone please explain?